# Convert discontinuous numpy array to continuous array Python

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.6

Hi I have a numpy array like

```
a = np.array([1,1,1,3,3,6,6,6,6,6,6])
```

I want to convert it to a continuous array like below

```
b = np.array([0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2])
```

I have a code for this using for loop

```
def fun1(a):
    b = a.copy()
    for i in range(1,a.shape[0]):
        if a[i] != a[i-1]:
            b[i] = b[i-1]+1
        else:
            b[i] = b[i-1]
    b = b - b.min()
    return b
```

Is there a way to vectorize this using `numpy`? I can use numba to make it faster but I was wondering if there is way to do it with just `numpy`.

Comment: Will the list always be sorted like this, increasing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following with [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html), using the `return_inverse` argument. According to the docs:

> return_inverse : bool, optional
>
> If True, also return the indices of the unique array (for the specified axis, if provided) that can be used to reconstruct ar.

```
a = np.array([1,1,1,3,3,6,6,6,6,6,6])
_, b = np.unique(a, return_inverse=True)

>>> b
array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])
```

**Edit** If the list starts out unsorted, and you want such a continuous array as displayed in your output, you can do the same as above, but passing a sorted array to `np.unique`:

```
a = np.array([1,3,1,3,3,6,6,3,6,6,6])
_, b = np.unique(sorted(a), return_inverse=True)
>>> b
array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])
```

Comment: Whoever down voted, mind to explain? This seems exactly what was asked.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but unless the user clarifies that the list will always be sorted, this is not a general solution.  Try it for `np.array([3,1,2])`  It will produce `[2 0 1]`.  The question that this is a dupe of explains this a bit better, and has a general alternative.

Comment: Thanks @chrisz. I tried to edit it to take that into account. Might still not be the best method, but I think it's a valid option.